# Synchronize blink animation for UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-animation, calayer

I want special `UITableViewCell`s to blink its borders. The problem is I can't synchronize borders blinking and my cells blink "randomly".
Here's what I have tried. I have `self.borderAnimationStartDate` to set initial time point. I add blinking animation when cell will be displayed and try to set "time offset" (`beginDate`) for cell's layer.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...
    if (myCondition)
    {
         Z9EmptySlotCell* emptySlotCell = (Z9EmptySlotCell*)cell;
         emptySlotCell.isNew = YES;

         [emptySlotCell.backgroundCellView.layer addAnimation:self.borderAnimation forKey:@"color"];
         emptySlotCell.backgroundCellView.layer.beginTime = -[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.borderAnimationStartDate];
        }
    }
}

- (CABasicAnimation*)borderAnimation
{
    if (!_borderAnimation)
    {
        _borderAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"borderColor"];
        _borderAnimation.fromValue = (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:231.0/255.0 blue:153.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
        _borderAnimation.toValue   = (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        _borderAnimation.duration = 2;
        _borderAnimation.repeatCount =  HUGE_VALF;
    }
    return _borderAnimation;
}
```

Comment: How do you set self.borderAnimationStartDate?

Comment: ZeMoon, now I just set it to `[NSDate date]` in `viewDidLoad`. In future I plan to set its value after adding some view

Comment: You have to use Notifications heavily, to achieve this.  It's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this functionality by using a NSTimer.

In you viewController, declare the NSTimer as either a property or an instance variable. Let's call it `blinkTimer`.

```
blinkTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(blinkCells) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[blinkTimer fire];
```

The blinkCells method can animate each visible cell as follows:

```
-(void)blinkCells
{
    NSArray *cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];

    for (UITableViewCell *cell in cells)
    {
        [cell.layer addAnimation:[self borderAnimation] forKey:@"color"];
    }
}
```

Make sure to remove the `repeatCount` line from the `[self borderAnimation]` method.

**EDIT:** In order to apply the animation to all the cells, you will need to collect them like so:

```
NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfSections]; ++i)
{
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; ++j)
    {
        [cells addObject:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i]]];
    }
}
```

You can collect them initially and store the cells in a property or instance variable.

Comment: Sorry, your solution doesn't work. I think, your solution use the same logic as mine, but you use `CFTimeInterval` instead of `NSTimeInterval`. Both are `double`, so after scrolling tableView a see async blinking :(

Comment: The difference is the value being passed as well. You can log the values to see it. Sorry to hear it didnt work. There is another way. You can use NSNotificationCenter along with a NSTimer to make each cell blink. I will edit my answer with this functionality.

Comment: I have also marked that all my cell's beginTime are the same. But blinking is async

Comment: now only `visibleCells` look good. But after scrolling the next bunch of cells is waiting 2 seconds for finishing

Comment: Well, then the animation needs to be applied to all the cells.

Comment: thanks. Your solution doesn't work perfectly. It is significantly after scrolling. But it is acceptable. Thank you